# Chrome DevTools not giving accurate mobile view compared to real mobile view

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to make my webpage mobile friendly. So, I am using Chrome DevTools to design a mobile version of my webpage. I have it the way I want it to look in DevTools. I uploaded it to my website & viewed it on a actual mobile phone & objects are not in the same places as they are in DevTools. I used the iPhone 6 mobile design in DevTools and also view it on an actual iPhone 6. They don't match. Anyone else have this problem? I have read articles about this, but don't know how to fix it. Any ideas? Should I use a different emulator?

**This is Chrome DevTools version on iPhone 6:**

[image: This is Chrome DevTools version on iPhone6]

**This is how it really looks on an iPhone 6:**

[image: Real iPhone layout]

Comment: Hi, I notice on your first screen shot of dev tools that the zoom is at %90. Can you try changing that to %100. Also are you able to scroll around on your iPhone browser or is that the full screen that you see?

Comment: its just restricting the view port, not actually simulating the device.

Comment: I changed it to 100% on DevTools & the ornaments still stay in the same position. Yes, I can scroll down on the iPhone browser. That's why you don't see the whole picture in the screenshot from the phone. In order to get a screenshot of the whole tree on the phone, I had to scroll down so it didn't capture the Merry Christmas sign at top. Why am I getting downgraded for asking this question?

Comment: I have used Safari's responsive mode & that really helps give a more accurate representation of what it will look like on a iPhone.

Comment: Dosen of times i faced same issue,so,always check on real mobile device after styling in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 10):

DevTools technical writer here. DevTools is just a simulation of mobile devices. It can't truly simulate an iPhone. So it's always a good idea to check how it actually looks on the devices that you care about (like you did). I don't think there's any bug or issue here. It's just an instance where the DevTools simulation doesn't reflect reality 100%.

Comment: As a web developer, we don't always have all the devices at our disposal. Emulation is all we got sometimes. Do you have other suggestions on how to get around this? We want our web sites to be consistent on every device, but it seems to be impossible

Comment: @KolobCanyon have you tried [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)?

Comment: Hi I also came across the issue. DevTools is already very helpful. The work you invest in this tools pays off because sooo many people are using it. So in case it's possible to improve the simulation for major devices like iphone, please follow the path. There are many, who cannot invest 30$ per month for one aspect.

Comment: Apparently it cannot replicate _any_ screen size realistically. For example, set Chrome to 2000 pixel wide, see its preview, then check how the lines of text break. Now, go to a screen that is by definition about twice as large. The lines will break earlier than on chrome preview :rofl: - in other words, it is pretty much useless. How comes?

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I think many front end devs would appreciate if you actually made it that.

Answer (score 1):

Mac users can use Xcode's [Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-your-app-in-simulator-or-on-a-device) (that's the actual name of the simulator) to emulate any Apple mobile device and see exactly how their website will appear on it.

You can use it to open Safari and access your `localhost`. I used it to fix issues on my website, issues that I could not reproduce in DevTools' device simulator.

[image]

Comment: which simulator? did you mean to drop a link there?

Comment: @ChumiestBucket If you own a Mac, it comes with an iOS simulator (called "Simulator") as part of Xcode. Simply search for "Simulator" in Spotlight (you may need to install Xcode if you haven't done so)

Comment: had no idea, thanks!

Comment: But only on mac

Answer (score -4):

Clear the cache for on your browser to ensure that your phone is accessing the most recent updates to your code.